# Sampling with a lens

Tags: optics, visible-light, lenses

First off, I'm a beginner optics experimenter so bear with me... I'm looking to sample a light source.  I am looking for a lens or prism that allows *most* of the light to pass through unaffected, while some of it is deflected to another direction, allowing me to monitor the light source without affecting its main path. I've looked into beam dividers and beam samplers, but I don't know enough about optics to know if this is what I need. Does something like this exist? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: See https://www.edmundoptics.com/optics/beamsplitters/

Answer (score 1):

A fancy beam splitter might work for you, but so might a simple piece of glass.  This is all going to depend on your light source, what exactly you mean by "sampling" it, and what exactly you mean by not "affecting its main path".  Are you just monitoring the power?  If so, you can probably get away with any old thin piece of glass placed in the beam at an angle.